# How to overlap two screens on button click

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created two ViewController in objective-c designed on storyboard. But my issue is that, i want to show like that (i have attached screenshot).[image]

Anybody can help me..

Comment: Just present another VC modally, with transparent background.

Comment: Can you provide coding part...

Comment: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"secondVC" sender:self];

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by SWRevealViewController as menu view from https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

Or take one view on firstViewController

Comment: Actually my problem is that, i have created two view controller and implement more coding of Api. So can you provide any other way..